# Urgent entry to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, emergencies

I'm writing on behalf of my aunt.

My aunt (a Philippines citizen) and uncle (UK citizen) live in Qatar where he worked. My uncle recently, and suddenly, passed away and we need to fly his body to the UK to have a funeral.

My aunt's visa doesn't start until 21st May 2019 and the Qatar Medical centre is unable to hold my uncle's body until this time. As my aunt is the next of kin, so she needs to travel with the body when it is transported.

My aunt has tried the UK embassy in Qatar who have written a statement to support her case in bringing the visa entry date forward but this is not a legal document, although it is stamped by the office.

This is obviously an urgent and sensitive situation, I have tried to help by calling the UK visa and immigration and hours later I'm still not through to speak to an actual person.  I'm told the query line that charge £1.37 is unable to assist with personal circumstances. However the UK embassy in Qatar has advised that someone in the UK needs to call on her behalf to help.

Any advice would be appreciated, we are desperate at this point.

Comment: The Medical Centre may be unable to hold the body, Hamad Hospital Mortuary should be able to arrange for the body to be respectfully and hygienically stored until it can be repatriated. This page (although intended for US citizens) gives information; note that the alternative of cremation and repatriation of ashes is not available as cremation is not available in Quatar. https://qa.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/death-of-a-u-s-citizen/

Comment: See also Quatar Airways guidance. https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/219623387-In-the-event-of-death-what-is-the-repatriation-procedure-for-human-remains-

Answer (score 2):

This question is over a month old, however when there is a difficult situation to sort out in another country it can help to engage the services of a local professional to help, in this case perhaps a lawyer. They can make phone calls on your behalf. A laywer could end up being expensive though and if money is an issue, there is the citizen advice bureau in the UK who give free advice for all sorts of situations and may direct you to someone who can help.

Comment: Can you add some references please?